# Orks Mob Rule in Warhammer 40k

Tags: warhammer-40k, orks, space-orks

I'm starting to play Warhammer 40k with Orks and I need a clarification to one of the rules for Orks.

Orks have **Mob Rule** so they can exchange their Leadership value with a number of models in unit. And if there are more then 11 models in unit with that rule this unit is given **Fearless** special rule (which make perfect sense because with 12 models you have 12 Ld value so you can't fail the test).

But the Fearless special rule isn't that great IMO because if changes leadership tests to wounds which in case of Ork Boyz means immediate casualties. This is written somewhere in manual where morale tests are explained but it's not mentioned in Special Abilities section of the manual. Can someone clarify if my understanding is correct or wrong, because this special ability sounds quite unfair.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid you do understand the ruling correctly (there is no GW statement on this that I'm aware of since there's no conflict in the two rules). The important thing to remember is that the substitution is optional - if you're likely to take massive damage from fearless, take a chance on the dice and use their adjusted leadership (adjusted for modifiers from the combat). I think that you will find that your decision on taking casualties vs risking a failed leadership check will greatly depend on the unit and what you're trying to do with it (a unit of 30 gretchin designed to hold up an assault squad is going to happily take the casualties while your boyz are likely to take their chances with a roll - though even these examples are dependent on what you're trying to do and the current situation on the table).